# apache flink statefun python sdk build distribution problem

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

I had plan to communicate embedded stateful functions with python statefun example (link: https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/tree/master/statefun-examples/statefun-python-greeter-example)

But (there is always a but) I had struggled to build python distribution. I think that I have the correct configurations.

[This was the error which I tried to described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in9Wj.jpg)

my pip version:19.2.3

my python version:3.7.5

by the way python sdk setup says its;

```
setup(
    name='apache-flink-statefun',
    version='2.1-SNAPSHOT',
    packages=["statefun"],
    url='https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun',
    license='https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0',
    license_files=["LICENSE", "NOTICE"],
    author='Apache Software Foundation',
    author_email='dev@flink.apache.org',
    description='Python SDK for Apache Flink Stateful functions',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    install_requires=['protobuf>=3.11.3,<4.0.0'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    python_requires='>=3.5',
    classifiers=[
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7']
)
```

It says it's ok with 3.7 python.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Flink runtime is primarily implemented on the JVM so the community uses JVM versioning schemes. `2.1-SNAPSHOT` is the current, unreleased version on master. It has not been released to PyPi.

The current stable version is `2.0.0`[1].

I'd encourage you to take a look at the documentation, which reflects the latest stable release[2].

[1] https://pypi.org/project/apache-flink-statefun/

[2] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-stable/